# Easiest way to find either 6, 8 or 10 alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: regex

Is there a shorter way to find an alphanumeric string for the size of 6, 8 or 10 characters?

```
^([[:alnum]]{6}|[[:alnum]]{8}|[[:alnum]]{10})$
```

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of the pattern.

```
^([[:alnum:]]{2}){3,5}$
```

Comment: Excellent! It couldn't be easier. Thanks very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}){3,5}
```

Comment: Important note: `:alnum` is not the same a `a-zA-Z0-9` because `:alnum` also includes non-ascii unicode characters. Your expression would miss out on accented and other characters.

Comment: To be specific, `[[:alnum:]]` is equivalent to `[\p{L}\p{N}]`.

Comment: A reference for `[:alnum:]` and other POSIX character classes is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes).